# What does char-table in Elisp contain?

Tags: emacs, elisp

When I set something to a char table, it creates extra inner char tables. For example:

```
ELISP> (setq *test-tbl* (make-char-table 'test 0))
#^[0 nil test 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

ELISP> (aset *test-tbl* 3 5)
5
ELISP> *test-tbl*
#^[0 nil test
     #^^[3 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     #^^[1 0
           #^^[2 0
                 #^^[3 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
                 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
           0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

ELISP>
```

What are `#^[...]` and `#^^[...]`? Why is char-table one dimensional when I first created, but after I set some value, it became a nested array?

Comment: Why are you using a char table? Read what they are by doing: M-: (info "(elisp) Char-Tables"), if you are trying to use them for some sort of program storage you are not using them correctly.

Comment: I read it here: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char_002dTable-Type.html . I tried it in the REPL and want to understand why it is represented that way.

Comment: First when I created it was a vector but after setting something using `aset`, according to: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char_002dTables.html#Char_002dTables and the case table changed into something like that nested vector.